# Convert data into xts in R with date format YYYYMMDD

Tags: r, xts

I have a time series table named `ff5` imported into `R` using `read.csv` with the `date` column in format of "YYYYMMDD".

I installed the `xts` package to better handle time series data. I tried to use the below code to convert the original data `ff5` to `xts` format:

```
library(xts)
ff5_xts <- xts(ff5, order.by = as.Date(ff5["date"], "%Y%m%d"))
```

And I got this error message:

> Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) :    do not know how to convert 'x'
>   to class “Date”

I tried a few other ways with or without `xts` but could not figure out how to convert this original data into time series.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you add as sample of your data in order to allow other to reproduce your error?

Comment: Following up on @Dave2e's good comment, you should review this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Although an example would be nice, this error is quite obvious. Read up on the difference between "[" and "[[". You needed to use: `as.Date(ff5[["date"]], "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: Because the error is "obvious" (indicative of a novice user), the sample data is of even greater importance.

Comment: Yes I am quite new to R. Thanks everyone for your helpful comments. I should have read a bit more about the rules of using this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
ff5 <- data.frame(date=c("20180615", "20180617", "20180616"))
ff5$date <- as.Date(ff5$date, "%Y%m%d")
library(xts)
ff5_xts <- xts(ff5, order.by = ff5$date)
ff5_xts
           date        
2018-06-15 "2018-06-15"
2018-06-16 "2018-06-16"
2018-06-17 "2018-06-17"
```

Comment: Dear Adam, thanks so much for your helps, this works!

Comment: @Alex Happy to hear that. Remember to check the green checkmark to indicate this solution works.